# How to output the results in an entry widget in tkinter

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I am struggling with this small application. I fallowed many forum and answer but I couldn't find the right answer.

I marked in the code the problems I am having:

- The first problem is I could not find a way for output the results in a ttk entry widget.
- The second problem is how to execute different code depending on the radiobutton checked.
- The third problem is how can I make the program with better syntax?

Code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class main_window:
    def __init__(self, master = None):

        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame1.pack()

        master.title('Calculation program')
        master.resizable(False, False)
        master.configure(background='blue')

        self.radiob1 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frame1, value="M", text="Molar (M)")
        self.radiob1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="nw", padx=25)
        self.radiob2 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frame1, value="mM", text="milliMolar (mM)")
        self.radiob2.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="nw", padx=25)

        self.mol_weight = ttk.Entry(self.frame1, width=24, font=('Arial', 10))
        self.mol_weight.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=3, pady=5)
        self.amount = ttk.Entry(self.frame1, width=24, font=('Arial', 10))
        self.amount.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=3, pady=5)
        self.results = ttk.Entry(self.frame1, width=15, font=('Cambria', 10))
        self.results.grid(row=6, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

        ttk.Label(self.frame1, text='Molecular Weight:').grid(row=0, column=1, padx=0, pady=3, sticky='w')
        ttk.Label(self.frame1, text='Amount:').grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0, pady=3, sticky='w')
        ttk.Label(self.frame1, text='Results').grid(row=5, column=3, padx=0, pady=6, sticky='s')

        ttk.Button(self.frame1, text='Calculate',
                   command=self.calculate).grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='e')
        ttk.Button(self.frame1, text='Clear',
                   command=self.clear).grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')

    def calculate(self):
        if self.radiob1.SELECTED??:
            return self.molare()
        elif self.radiob2.SELECTED??:
            return self.millimolar
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(title="No good, you have to select one!")
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Calculations', message='Calculations Completed!')

    def molare(self):
        a = self.mol_weight.get()
        b = self.amount.get()
        ans = a + b
        self.results["Results"] = "Is: " + ans [???]

    def millimolar(self):
        a = self.mol_weight.get()
        b = self.amount.get()
        ans = a - b
        self.results["Results"] = "Is: " + ans  [???]

    def clear(self):
        self.mol_weight.delete(0, 'end')
        self.amount.delete(0, 'end')
        self.radiob1.DESELECT() ??
        self.radiob2.DESELECT()??

def main():
    root = Tk()
    Main_window = main_window(root)
    root.mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Comment: `"Is " + str(and)` or `"Is {}".format(ans)` or `"Is %d" % ans` but first `ans = int(a) + int(b)` or `ans = float(a) + float(b)` because `a` and `b` are strings.

Comment: some `tkinter` doc: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm - It describe `tk`, not `ttk` but most widgets has the same options/methods

Comment: you can use single `StrinVar` with  both `Radiobutton(variables=...)` to get and set selection.

Comment: remove old text `self.results.delete(0, 'end')` and put new text `self.results.insert( 0, "Hello World")`. Or use `StringVar` with `Entry(textvariable=...)`. See link in previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To put text in an Entry widget, use the `insert` method:

```
entry.delete(0, "end") # clear entry
entry.insert(0, "my text") # insert new text
```

2) Associate a StringVar with your radiobuttons and use its `get` method to know which button is selected

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def callback():
    if var.get() == "r1":
        print("r1 is selected")
    elif var.get() == "r2":
        print("r2 is selected")
    else:
        print("None")

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar(root, value="")
ttk.Radiobutton(root, variable=var, value="r1", text="r1").pack()
ttk.Radiobutton(root, variable=var, value="r2", text="r2").pack()
ttk.Button(root, text="print", command=callback).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

To clear the radiobutton selection, you can do `var.set("")`.

3) It's a rather subjective question. First, class name are usually capitalized. Personally, I make my `Main` class inherit from `tk.Tk`:

```
class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        # window configuration
        self.title('Calculation program')
        #... 
        # widgets
        ttk.Label(self, text="example").grid()
        #... 

        self.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

And, as it was said in the comments, `a` and `b` should be converted to float or int before making calculations and then do `"Is %d" % ans` or any of the other proposition of furas in the comments.

I recommend you this website: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html to get the list of all options and methods of each tkinter/ttk widget.